# PayPal Mobile SDK Classic API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Two main questions
Using the PayPal Mobile SDK for iOS

Have have the following two lines

```
[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"APP-11111111111"}];
[paypalConfig setMerchantName:@"ABC Co"];
```

1) What else is needed to assign the sandbox payment to the app / account

2) I have processed two sandbox payments got a state = approved , but where do you check where that money is waiting ?  The payment has been "made"  so where is it pending ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The new v2 mSDKs no longer use an AppID to connect. The only information used to connect to your account would be your Client ID. The latest version of the iOS SDK can be found [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK).

Once you process a payment with the mSDK and it's approved in the sandbox, the funds should be showing in your -facilitator sandbox account.

Comment: Thanks  But I'm still not able to verify the payment  Verify a mobile payment.  I get the Payment and the ID = PAY-……. state = approved. But when I call the https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-…..  I get a 401  response  and NO proof of payment.   Please help

Comment: Are you using the same client ID as you are in the mobile SDK? Keep in mind that you also have to use the associated client secret in the payment lookup call.

Comment: So Bearer {accessToken}   should be Bearer  APP-……    Is this right ?

Comment: No, accessToken is not the same as the App ID.  Find information on generating an access token at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/ under section 2 for getting an access token.